Windows Hypervisor Platform Restart Issue in AMD processor laptop
I enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform in my AMD laptop. but when i restart the laptop then it does not start. Always I have to Reset and format the Local C data from the laptop. Is there any solution so that I have enabled Windows Hypervisor Platform and also does not need to Reset everything from the laptop?
I did enabled SVM from bios and still I am facing issue because of that.
